# TensorFlow 2.0: how to group graph using tf.keras? tf.name_scope/tf.variable_scope not used anymore?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

Back in TensorFlow < 2.0 we used to define layers, especially more complex setups like *inception modules* for example, by grouping them with `tf.name_scope` or `tf.variable_scope`.

Utilizing these operators we were able to conveniently structure the compute graph, which results in TensorBoard's graph view being interpretable much easier.

Just one example for the structured groups:
[image]

This comes in very handy for debugging complex architectures.

Unfortunately, `tf.keras` seems to ignore `tf.name_scope` and `tf.variable_scope` is gone in TensorFlow >= 2.0. Thus, a solution like this...

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    with tf.variable_scope("bar"):
        v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
        assert v.name == "foo/bar/v:0"
```

...is not available anymore. Is there any replacement?

How can we group layers and entire models in TensorFlow >= 2.0? If we do not group layers, `tf.keras` is creating a big mess for complex models by just placing everything serially in the graph view.

Is there a replacement for `tf.variable_scope`? I could not find any so far, but made heavy use of the method in TensorFlow < 2.0.

---

**EDIT**: I have now implemented an example for **TensorFlow 2.0**. This is a simple GAN implemented using `tf.keras`:

```
# Generator
G_inputs = tk.Input(shape=(100,), name=f"G_inputs")

x = tk.layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 16)(G_inputs)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
x = tk.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tk.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 16))(x)

x = tk.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tk.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
x = tf.image.resize(x, (14, 14))

x = tk.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tk.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
x = tf.image.resize(x, (28, 28))

x = tk.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tk.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)

x = tk.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)

G_model = tk.Model(inputs=G_inputs,
                   outputs=x,
                   name="G")
G_model.summary()

# Discriminator
D_inputs = tk.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name=f"D_inputs")

x = tk.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(D_inputs)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
x = tk.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = tk.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
x = tk.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = tk.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)

x = tk.layers.Flatten()(x)

x = tk.layers.Dense(128)(x)
x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
x = tk.layers.Dense(64)(x)
x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
x = tk.layers.Dense(1)(x)
x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)

D_model = tk.Model(inputs=D_inputs,
                   outputs=x,
                   name="D")

D_model.compile(optimizer=tk.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, beta_1=0.5, name="Adam_D"),
                loss="binary_crossentropy")
D_model.summary()

GAN = tk.Sequential()
GAN.add(G_model)
GAN.add(D_model)
GAN.compile(optimizer=tk.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, beta_1=0.5, name="Adam_GAN"),
            loss="binary_crossentropy")

tb = tk.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="./tb_tf2.0", write_graph=True)

# dummy data
noise = np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float32)
target = np.ones(shape=(100, 1), dtype=np.float32)

GAN.fit(x=noise,
        y=target,
        callbacks=[tb])
```

The **graph in TensorBoard** of these models looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gQf2.png). The layers are just a complete mess and also the models "G" and "D" (on the right side) covers some mess. "GAN" is completely missing. The training operation "Adam" cannot be opened properly: too many layers just plotted from left to right and arrows all over the place. Very hard to check the correctness of your GAN this way.

---

Althought a **TensorFlow 1.X** implementation of the same GAN covers lots of "boilerplate code"...

```
# Generator
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100], name="Z")


def model_G(inputs, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("G", reuse=reuse):
        x = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 7 * 7 * 16)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 7, 7, 16))

        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, 32, (3, 3), padding="same")
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
        x = tf.image.resize_images(x, (14, 14))

        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, 32, (3, 3), padding="same")
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
        x = tf.image.resize_images(x, (28, 28))

        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, 32, (3, 3), padding="same")
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)

        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, 1, (3, 3), padding="same")
        G_logits = x
        G_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)

    return G_logits, G_out


# Discriminator
D_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], name="D_in")


def model_D(inputs, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("D", reuse=reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv"):
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, 32, (3, 3), padding="same")
            x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
            x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, (2, 2), (2, 2))
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, (3, 3), padding="same")
            x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
            x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, (2, 2), (2, 2))
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 64, (3, 3), padding="same")
            x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)

        with tf.variable_scope("dense"):
            x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 7 * 7 * 64))

            x = tf.layers.dense(x, 128)
            x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
            x = tf.layers.dense(x, 64)
            x = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
            x = tf.layers.dense(x, 1)
            D_logits = x
            D_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)

    return D_logits, D_out

# models
G_logits, G_out = model_G(Z)
D_logits, D_out = model_D(D_in)
GAN_logits, GAN_out = model_D(G_out, reuse=True)

# losses
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="target")
d_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logits, labels=target))
gan_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=GAN_logits, labels=target))

# train ops
train_d = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-5, name="AdamD") \
    .minimize(d_loss, var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="D"))
train_gan = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-5, name="AdamGAN") \
    .minimize(gan_loss, var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="G"))

# dummy data
dat_noise = np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float32)
dat_target = np.ones(shape=(100, 1), dtype=np.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
tf_init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(tf_init)

# merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./tb_tf1.0", sess.graph)

ret = sess.run([gan_loss, train_gan], feed_dict={Z: dat_noise, target: dat_target})
```

...the resulting [TensorBoard graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS1vY.png) looks considerably cleaner. Notice how clean "AdamD" and "AdamGAN" scopes are on the top right. You can directly check that your optimizers are attached to the right scopes / gradients.

Comment: AFAIK, just using `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(..., name='conv_1')` works. Or could you please be more specific?

Comment: So you have to set names manually like `name='modelX/scopeY/layerZ'`? That was a lot easier with `tf.variable_scope` before.

Comment: As of today, the only other option i know is to use separate keras models.

Comment: @daniel451 Can you give a simple example where you were not able to use keras to fit your needs? If you give a minimal example, maybe I can show you actually don't need the variable scoping

Comment: @mlRocks I have added an easy sample implementation of a GAN to the question now, implemented in both, TF 1.X and TF 2.0 using `tf.keras`. Please see the attached images to compare the graph created by TF 2.0 with the one from TF 1.X using variable scopes.

Comment: Try this once and check if this is like what you need:
`img_input = Input(shape=(224,224,3), name='Img_input')
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', name='Conv1')(img_input)
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
z = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
model = Model(img_input, z, name='sample_model')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
tb = TensorBoard('logs', write_graph=True)
model.fit(random_input, random_output, callbacks=[tb], epochs=1, batch_size=8)
`

Answer (score 3):

According to the community RFC [Variables in TensorFlow 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180817-variables-20.md):

> - to control variable naming users can use tf.name_scope + tf.Variable

Indeed, [`tf.name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) still exists in TensorFlow 2.0, so you can just do:

```
with tf.name_scope("foo"):
    with tf.name_scope("bar"):
        v = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32, name="v")
        assert v.name == "foo/bar/v:0"
```

Also, as the point above that states:

> - the tf 1.0 version of variable_scope and get_variable will be left in tf.compat.v1

So you can just fall back to [`tf.compat.v1.variable_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/variable_scope) and [`tf.compat.v1.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/get_variable) if you really need to.

Variable scopes and `tf.get_variable` can be convenient but are riddled with minor pitfalls and corner cases, specially since they behave similarly but not exactly like name scopes, and it is actually a parallel mechanism to it. I think having just name scopes will be more consistent and straightforward.

Comment: I have added an easy sample implementation of a GAN now to the question, implemented in both, TF 1.X and TF 2.0 using `tf.keras`. Please see the attached images to compare the graph created by TF 2.0 with the one from TF 1.X using variable scopes.

Comment: @daniel451 Have you tried putting the generator code, from `G_inputs = ...` to just before `G_model = ...` within a `with tf.name_scope('G'):`? And similarly for the discriminator.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that: no difference. It seems layers created by `tf.keras.layers` completely ignore `tf.name_scope`.

Comment: @daniel451 did you also open an issue on TF's GitHub? This seems like a bug/missing feature in the implementation of TF's Keras (TF 2.0 is still an alpha, after all..)

Comment: Just found this issue [Tensorflow 2.0 tf.name_scope has no effect on weights created by keras functional api](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27298) created 3 days ago that seems to ask the very same question.

Comment: For creating weights, it has no effects. The code will prompt reuse=True, but no such functions.